# How I can one component to another component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How I can add component CountryName and component CountryCapital to component Country ?

Display lists in browser:

> Russia
>
> Moscow
>
> France
>
> Paris

### data.js

```
export default  [{  
id: 1,

name: 'France',
capital: 'Paris',
    },


    {   
        id: 2,
        name: 'Russia',
        capital: 'Moscow'
     }];
```

### First component CountryName.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class CountryName extends Component {
    render() {



const {data} = this.props;
        const CountryName = data.map(country => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h2>{country.name}</h2>
                </div>                  
            )   
}) 

        return (
                    <div>
                        {CountryName}
                    </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CountryName;
```

### Second component CountryCapital.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class CountryCapital extends Component {

    render() {

        const {data} = this.props;
        const CountryCapital = data.map(country => {
            return (
            <div>
                <p>{country.capital}</p>
            </div>

            )   
        }) 

        return (
                    <div>
                        {CountryCapital}
                    </div>
        );
    }
}


export default MovieDescription;
```

### Third  component Country.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import CountryName from './CountryName';
import CountryCapital from './CountryCapital';


class Country extends Component {

    render() {

        const {data} = this.props;
        const country = data.map(country => {
            return (
                <li key = {country.id}> 


                </li>
            )   
        }) 

        return (
                    <ul>
                        {Country}
                    </ul>
        );
    }
}


export default Country;
```

### App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Country from './components/Country';

class App extends Component {
    render() {

        return (

            <div>
                <Country data={this.props.data}/>

            </div>
        )

    }
}

export default App;

//HTML:

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>`
```

Comment: What do you mean? If you want to add component CountryName and component CountryCapital to component Country, just import it!

Comment: I import it. Look at my code.But I don't know what I have to write between " return <li key = {country.id}> </li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your components are structured in a way that, it will first list down all country names one by one and then list down country capitals one by one.

Since your requirement is to display Country and its capital as a group (like listed together in each line), you don't need two components. And in your Country component, just call the newly written component to display it as a group.

Something like this will work. Combine CountryName and CountryCapital to a single component (CountryData) like below.

```
const {data} = this.props;
const CountryData = data.map(country => {
        return (
            <div>
                <div><h2>{country.name}</h2></div>
                <div><h2>{country.capital}</h2></div>
            </div>                  
        )   
})
return (
        <div>
          {CountryData}
        </div>
    );
```

And in your Component Country, call this new component and pass props like:

```
import CountryData from './CountryData';
......
......
render() {

    const {data} = this.props;
    return (
        <CountryData data={this.props.data} />
    );
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

**Error:  JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag**

```
            return (
            <div><h2>{country.name}</h2></div>
            <div><h2>{country.capital}</h2></div>
               ^
        )
    })
```

Comment: You missed a <div> wrapping in your return.                                      `<div>                                                                                                                                                                             <div><h2>{country.name}</h2></div>
            <div><h2>{country.capital}</h2></div>                                       </div>`

Comment: If you could add more information on what errors you are getting, it would be helpful.

Comment: praveenweb: Thank you very much  for your help. It's work :)

Comment: Where I can put key id ?  const MovieData = data.map(movie => {
        return (
            <li key = {country.id}>
                <div><h2>{country.title}</h2></div>
                <div><p>{country.desc}</p></div>
            </li>                  
        )   
})